# React doesn't keep or send cookies to Node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, postman

I have a Node app with this simplified API that checks if user is authenticated (with session):

```
export default (req, res,) => {
  if (!req.session || !req.session.loggedIn) {
    return res.status(401).send();
  }
  return res.status(200).send();
};
```

In Postman everything works well, but when React client makes this request:

```
axios.get(`${domain}/is-auth`)
  .then((res) => {
    return res.status === 200;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    throw err;
  });
```

... it always gets 401 and return false. The server can't see its session. I am reading it's about cookies but aren't cookies supposed to be kept and sent by browser automatically? If not then how I can do that? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch` and `axios` indeed do not send credentials automatically with the request, you will have to specify it by setting the "withCredentials" option to **true**:

```
axios.get(`${domain}/is-auth`, { withCredentials: true })
  .then((res) => {
    return res.status === 200;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    throw err;
  });
```

Comment: Oh thanks! Although I changed it to make it based on JWT and done manually, but good to know.